# Ho do I update to 13.04 from the beta?

Tags: command-line, upgrade

I usually use:

`sudo apt-get update;sudo apt-get upgrade;sudo apt-get dist-upgrade;sudo apt-get autoremove`

To update my system which is the 13.04 beta, is there anything special I need to do to get onto the latest version or are the commands I'm using enough for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The beta becomes `13.04` when it is released, so if you've done an upgrade on or after the release date you should be running equivalent versions as if you'd directly installed `13.04`.

(Depending on what point you started the beta, it is possible that you will still have some cruft from beta versions of various software left around - but if you're running `apt-get autoremove` you should have got rid of most of it. You might want to install and run `deborphan` as well, which can find other redundant packages.)